# Ports on the Android PHONE

Tags: wi-fi, networking, firewall

I often use my *Samsung Galaxy Note2* on local WiFi networks which are protected by a firewall, and experience problems with some apps which are most likely caused by strict firewall rules.

Is there somewhere a list of ports to open for the apps on our Android devices (e.g. Facebook, Google play app., etc)?

And last the Google play store port was 5228, did they change it again???

Comment: I doubt that's on-topic here. We deal with issues/questions from a user's point of view. Put into this context, what purpose shall such a port-list serve?

Comment: Then we all no what ports to open on our firewall so that we can use our Android Phones from behind an Firewall.

Comment: OK, you've made your point -- that makes it an end-user question. I hope you don't mind if I include this fact directly with the question, to make it clearer? If needed for firewall rules, it's e.g. not necessary to have explanations for each port, and in some cases even "port ranges" might be fine.

Comment: Btw: Until someone comes up with a port list, you might want to take a look at e.g. [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor). In its "connections" tab it shows you which apps hold what open connections, including the ports used -- so you can at least collect the most important ones yourself.

Comment: Thx Budd.. you better than Google today :-)

Comment: Only today? #D If you count "ways to figure out the ports yourself" as answer, too, let me know -- and I compile something for you.